# Binary operation english terminology

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition, binary-operations

**Foreword:**

I have read R.H. Bruck's *A Survey of binary systems*, where the notion of **halfoperation** is given. A halfoperation $\ast$ differs from a (binary) operation since $a\ast b$ may not be defined for all ordered pairs $(a,b)$. For example, from the Cayley table

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}\ast & 0 & 1\\ \hline 0 & 0 & 1\\1 & & 0\end{array}$$

we deduce that $0\ast 1=1$ while $1\ast 0$ is not defined ($(0,1)$ belongs to the *range* of the halfoperation, $(1,0)$ does not).

Let us now consider two well known operations over $\mathbb{R}^3$:

1. *vector product*: ${\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3}\qquad{(a,b)\mapsto a\wedge b}$,
2. *scalar product*: ${\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}}\qquad{(a,b)\mapsto a\cdot b}$.

In italian (my native language) we call both of them binary operation:

1. *operazione binaria interna* one like vector product (*interna*: "inner" or "internal"),
2. *operazione binaria esterna* one like scalar product (*esterna*: "outer" or "external").

**Question:**

Does such distinction exist in english? I found no traces of it in literature and, reading papers, forums [and SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298647/what-is-binary-operation-is-division-a-binary-operation), I have experienced that this matter may sometimes give raise to ambiguities or misunderstanding.

How should we properly call an operation like subtraction $-$ over $\mathbb{N}$, since $a-b$ only belongs to $\mathbb{N}$ if $a\ge b$? Halfoperation over $\mathbb{N}$?

How should we properly call an operation like scalar product $\cdot$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$, since $a\cdot b$ exists for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$ but never belongs to $\mathbb{R}^3$? Is this not a binary operation while vector product is?

**And, above all:**

In the end the word *binary*, alone, means that the operation is a function of two variables (its [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) is $2$), but does not deal with [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics))...

...Right?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/713756/55235). Regarding the last section, see the quote in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/586824) answer.

Comment: @Git Gud: I am reading...again and again, I'll ask you further details. I want to get proper understanding of the vocabulary choices. What about scalar product? "external binary"? Oh c'mon we're not *only interested in internal binary*, do we? Glad "Related" and not "duplicate" ;)

Comment: I'm not the right person to discuss this, for all I care one could use words such as *senbonzakura* or *kageyoshi* to mean *natural number* and *plane* respectively. All I care about is that the things are properly defined.

Comment: @Git Gud: Manga & Math. Stright Edge. Good nite.

Comment: A "function" which do not always return a value, such that $f(x)$ is undefined, sometimes, is called a "partial function", so maybe "partila binary operation" will do?

Comment: There was a time when the term " function" was defined in a broader sense. In old books, the requirement  was only that no $x$ in A should be associated with more than one $y$ in B. So the case where an $x$ in the domain  has no image did not prevent the relation to be a function.

Comment: French mathematicians still say " internal law of composition" and " external law of composition" . I may be wrong, but I think that in the past, this terminology was used in the english speaking mathematical literature ( maybe under the influence of Bourbaki). But I think that nowadays, the terminology is outdated.